# Floating Div Bug In Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

having an issue here thast driving me nuts

[image]

If you look there .. the form is pushed down in
chrome but not in firefox.

I tried clear both , overflow hidden..

Here is the shell of the code

```
<div style="margin: auto; width: 900px; padding:15px; overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="position:relative;float:right;margin-top:10px; right:5%;padding-right:20px;">
      <center>
        RIGHT SIDE
      </center>
      <div class="testimonials">BLA BLA</div>          
    </div>
  <form novalidate action="" id="mainform" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$affId;?>" name="affilate" >
    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$PurchaseType;?>" name="PurchaseType" id="PurchaseType">     
    <table style="width:820px;">
      <colgroup>
      <col style="width:128px;">
      <col style="width:337px;">
      <col style="width:20px;">
      <col style="width:255px">
      </colgroup>
    </table>
  </form>
<br class="clear" />
</div>
```

Any help appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Your code shell doesn't resemble your issue at all, especially since you have a bunch of <col> tags that are not closed. Can you make a jsfiddle demonstrating your issue?

Comment: hm, html validation? in some cases an missing closing div or so

Comment: In my experience chrome calculates 1px more in some cases. Try to change width 1 px less and see if it helps. I mean on the part that drops down, do it 1 px less.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, the problem was because I was using `margin-top:10px` on chrome it was causing problem.

You should try using `padding-top:10px`.